# Relationships among these models in Django

Tags: python, django, database

I want to build a website where:

- there is a set of 10 Cards
- on each Card, there are Important/Not_Important/Unknown attributes
- each User chooses which card are important and not important (from the same set of 10 Cards)
- his choices are saved and linked to his account.

I have come up with models like these:

1. User: I use `django.contrib.auth.models.User`
2. Card:

   ```
   class Card(models.Model):
       is_important = models.NullBooleanField(default=None)
   ```
3. CardSet:

   ```
   class CardSet(models.Model):

       cards = models.ManyToManyField(Card)

       user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='card_set')
   ```

It is obvious to me this database relationship has something wrong because, I don't know how to retrieve a list of cards that an instance of User has decided to be important/not important/unknown. However, I don't know how to put them in right relationship.

Comment: For this, you need a custom [through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: you can query this as well `CardSet.objects.filter(user__username='abhishek.garg', cards__is_important=True)` , you need to read about chaining filters, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters

Comment: Thank you Burhan Khalid and abhishekgarg!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have found the solution to my question: 
The models would be like this :

```
class Card(models.Model):
    card_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=False)

class Choice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card)
    is_important = models.NullBooleanField(default=None)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user','card')
```

The key to the answer is to use **unique_together** Meta option.

Please review my solution and if you have a better solution or any alternative solution, please feel free to suggest. I can learn a lot from yours.

Thanks!