# Django model attributes

Tags: python, django, class

when I try to run the code below, it is said by Django : "name 'cards' is not defined. "

```
class CardSet(models.Model):

    cards = Card.objects.all()

    def show_card(self):

        for card in cards:
            print(card)
```

but if I put the code like this, it works.

```
class CardSet(models.Model):

    def show_card(self):

        cards  = Card.objects.all()
        for card in cards :
            print(card)
```

Can you explain for me please ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your code (rather than the posted code which has at least one syntax error):

```
class CardSet(models.Model):
    cards = Card.objects.all()
    def show_card(self):
        for card in cards:
            print(card)
```

This one has many problems:

1. You will not use `Card.objects.all()` but a many2many field. See the docs for more details. Otherwise your method would not make sense as instance method.
2. The loop in the method does not have the scope of the class, since that scope exists only while you define the class (which occurs on loading, not on method invocation).
3. Your method involved `self`, perhaps the reference you want is `self.cards` instead of `cards`.

Proposed code:

```
class CardSet(modelsModel):
    cards = models.ManyToManyField(Card)
    def show_cards(self):
        for card in self.cards.all():
            print(card)
```

OTOH if `cards` is just a class-scoped queryset and not a m2m relationship...

```
class CardSet(modelsModel):
    cards = Card.objects.all()
    def show_cards(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            print(card)
```

The solution is essentially the same: add `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Access it using `self.cards`:

```
def show_card(self):
    for card in self.cards:
        print (card)
```

**Edit:** I saw your other question [Relationships among these models in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990027/relationships-among-these-models-in-django)

If you kept that relationship, simply query using a related object query:

```
cards = models.ManyToManyField(Card) # Ref. this relationship

def show_card(self):
    for card in self.cards.all(): # <-- querying for cards related to this
                                  # CardSet object 
        print (card)
```

Comment: Thank you for your instant answer. Both of you have given me invaluable helps. It's hard to decide which one is the best answer, I chose Lui's because he has less point than you. Hope that you don't mind!  '